# Parse a file into a dictionary of arrays

Tags: python, file, parsing, dictionary

I have a csv file with rows of device data like the following:

```
#file.csv
devA,x1,y1
devB,x1,y1
devA,x2,y2
devC,x1,y1
devC,x2,y2
devA,x3,y3
```

I want to make a dictionary that makes arrays of the data points, with the device names for keys:

```
{
    'devA':[
            [x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]
         ],
    'devB':[
            [x1,y1]
         ],
    'devC':[
            [x1,y1],[x2,y2]
         ]
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#dict.py
import csv,datetime

with open('file.dat', 'rb') as csvfile:
    dataReader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    book={row[0]:[row[1],row[2]] for row in dataReader}
print book
```

but this outputs

```
$ ./dict.py 
{'devC': ['x6', 'y6'], 'devB': ['x2', 'y2'], 'devA': ['x7', 'y7']}
```

I think I see the problem is my `book=` line is replacing the contents of each key instead of appending.  How can I go about getting the desired result in a "Python" way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dict.setdefault` method to create your expected dictionary :

```
my_dict={}
with open('file.dat', 'rb') as csvfile:
    dataReader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    for name,item1,item2 in dataReader:
         my_dict.setdefault(name,[]).append([item1,item2])
```

If you are using python 3.X you can use unpacking assingement in your loop  :

```
for name,*items in dataReader:
    my_dict.setdefault(name,[]).append(items)
```

Comment: I keep seeing the `*` come up with things like this (e.g, `*zip`).  Could you explain what it means and/or if I should bother learning it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `collections.defaultdict:`

```
import collections
with open("your_file") as f:
    my_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        line = line.split(",")
        my_dict[line[0]].append(line[1:])
```